# How can I make sure and print only the numbers I need?

Tags: java, arrays, count

I am currently working in Java and have a problem that reads: Write a program that reads the integers between 1 and 100 and counts the occurrences of each.
Assume the input ends with 0.

I have been able to get the program to print out numbers and occurrences, however it prints the correct information, then follows it with "n appears" with a consecutively smaller number.

Example: Input: 2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2 0
Output:
The number 2 appears 2 times.
The number 2 appears 1 time.        (Need this to go away)
The number 3 appears 1 time.
The number 4 appears 1 time.
The number 5 appears 2 times.
The number 5 appears 1 time.        (Need this to go away)
The number 6 appears 1 time.
The number 23 appears 1 time.
The number 43 appears 1 time.

Here is my code: (still learning so it may not be concise or may appear messy)

```
public class CountOccur {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        
        int[] userNums = new int[100];
        int userNum = -1, i = 0, count = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Enter some integers between 1 and 100 (0 when     
done): ");
    
        do {
            userNum = input.nextInt();
            userNums[i] = userNum;
            i++;
            count++;
        } while (userNum != 0);
    
        int[] userNumsNoZero = new int[count - 1];
        
        for (i = 0; i < userNumsNoZero.length; i++) {
            userNumsNoZero[i] = userNums[i];
        }
        
        java.util.Arrays.sort(userNumsNoZero);
        
        for (i = 0; i < userNumsNoZero.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(userNumsNoZero[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < userNumsNoZero.length; i++) {
            count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < userNumsNoZero.length; j++) {
                if (userNumsNoZero[i] == userNumsNoZero[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 1) {
                System.out.print("The number " + userNumsNoZero[i] + 
" appears " + count + " times.\n");
            } else {
                System.out.print("The number " + userNumsNoZero[i] + 
" appears " + count + " times.\n");
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

I have tried using methods to create and count the array. I have also tried moving the print statement to different locations. I am able to get it to print "The number 2 appears 2 times" correctly, but then it does not print any of the integers that appear 1 time.

Comment: You could check to see if there are any elements of `userNumsNoZero` *before* index `i` with the current number; if there are, that means you've already printed out that number.

Comment: However, knowing that all of the numbers are between 1 and 100 means you can solve this the way a person would: keep track of the count for each number as you read them in, and then just print the counts for those that have a non-0 count.

Comment: You can make this tons easier by using a second array of size 100 that holds the frequencies. Or use a `Map`

Comment: @ScottHunter I was able to implement your first suggestion and it works perfectly. I think that is what I have been trying to do the whole time, I kept confusing myself with all the various ways I was attempting to count. I also tried the array to hold frequencies and I was able to get the arrays to print correctly, but still had the problem with printing duplicates.

Comment: For future reference, what you want is known as a "frequency distribution". Frequency distributions are often presented visually as histograms.

Answer (score 2):

Java has many excellent collections that are more concise and easier than using array and index, I will recommend you to use Map to deal with this issue:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        int num;
        System.out.println("Enter some integers between 1 and 100 (0 when done): ");
        while ((num = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
            if (num >= 1 && num <= 100) {
                result.put(num, result.getOrDefault(num, 0) + 1);
            }
        }
        result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("The number " + k + " appears " + v + " times."));
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that it is counting and printing the occurrences without checking if the number has been counted before.

One way to fix this is to add another check to see if the current number has already been counted. If it has, you skip counting and printing it again.

Also, you can optimize your program by eliminating the need to create a second array `userNumsNoZero`.

Here's the corrected version of your program:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountOccur {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new Scanner object for reading input from the console
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Initialize an array to keep track of the occurrence of each number.
        // Indexes represent the numbers (1-100), and the values represent their counts.
        int[] counts = new int[101]; // There are 100 possible numbers (1 to 100), index 0 is ignored.

        // Prompt the user for input
        System.out.println("Enter some integers between 1 and 100 (0 when done): ");

        // Loop to read numbers from the user until 0 is entered
        int number;
        while ((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
            // Increment the count for the input number if it is between 1 and 100
            if (number >= 1 && number <= 100) {
                counts[number]++;
            }
        }

        // Iterate over the counts array to print the occurrences of each number
        for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {
            if (counts[i] > 0) {
                // Output the occurrence of each number that has been entered
                System.out.println("The number " + i + " appears " + counts[i] + " times.");
            }
        }

        // Close the scanner
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it is always nice to see a different perspective! I did run the code and it also did exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

to eliminate duplicates you should update `i` to next sequence of integers of same value. In current code, you could add this:

```
for (i = 0; i < userNumsNoZero.length; i++) {
            count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < userNumsNoZero.length; j++) {
                if (userNumsNoZero[i] == userNumsNoZero[j]) {
                    count++;
                    i = j; // <--- this is new code!
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been trying to do, thank you for the code suggestion.

Comment: @AlexTaraba here is your code with my one line fix: https://ideone.com/OreBsP, the results looks ok to me.